# How to run select statment using batch file?

Tags: sql, batch-file, sql-server-2000, osql

I need to query sql server database using batch file. I put these cmdlines in the batch file.  When I run the batch file. Cursor stays there after making trusted connection.

```
OSQL -E 
use db1
SELECT count(*) FROM table_01 t1 
left join table_02 t2 on t1.tableID = t2.tableID 
WHERE t1.Date < '20110724' 
Go
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Did you look up osql in, say, Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

osql has a simple fature.

For example I run an SQL command from e:\backupdb.txt with

```
osql -S servername -U user -P password -i e:\backupdb.txt
```

it does the job

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I do it.

First, build the SQL script that you want, and store it as a simple text file.

Next, use SQLCMD (or OSQL or, perish the thought, ISQL) to call that file, something like so:

```
SQLCMD -S %1 -E -b -h-1 -I -d tempdb -i BulkDeploy.txt  > BulkDeploy_%DateString%.txt
```

Where:

- S  specifies the SQL instance server (here, specified with the first batch parameter)
- E  use NT authentication
- b  if SQL hits an error, return a value that the batch ERRORLEVEL can pick up and process
- h-1  return no header rows (IF datasets are returned)
- I  set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER on (this blew up in my face *once*, I forget how or why, and I've included it ever since)
- d  database to connect to
- i  execute the following script and exit when done
- >  directs any output to the specified file for subsequent processing

SQLCMD et. al. have many parameters, check them out in Books Online. Further subtleties can be achieved with batch parameters.